# How to add extra row to QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt

Good day, i have a model for QTreeView, i add QSortFilterProxyModel for this widget, hiding the branches and thus a would have a QTreeView like QListView but with headers.All work properly, now i would like to add new extra row(which displaying on my view, when clicking on this row i move up to the parent of this nodes).How to impliment this behavior:1)Add extra row;2)Clicking on the view and move up to the parent and displaying new nodes.

Comment: Answer to second question is: When signal click was catch, then you can do somthing like this QTreeView *v = qobject_cast<QTreeView*>(sender());
 if(v)
 {
  v->setRootIndex(index);
 } after this actions QTreeView look like QListView(if hided branches).The first question is open now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I met same problem, I designed new ProxyModel, which only purpose was to add empty row after proxies previous rows from source model. Then you can insert this model between view and sorting model.

Comment: How you implement this?How you copy data to another proxy model?You cannot add 2 rows for one call function!

Comment: @TopilskiAlexandr, well, it does not literally copies and inserts. Is proxy model, it accepts source model and represent its data transformed. No any data copying.

Comment: I understand, but where i create the new row, where i set to this row data?

Comment: @TopilskiAlexandr, In your proxy model. It just states that it has sourcemodel + 1 rows and when requested last row data, it is your additional row data.